# ¿Como usar las comillas dobles y simples en una cadena en PHP para irsertar en MYSQL?

Tags: php

Tengo este texto guardado en esta variable :

```
$variable: Tuberia de acero al carbono Ø4" sch 40 ;

$idDetalle = 1;
```

lo que quiero es insertar esto en una columna de una tabla de MYSQL pero no respeta las comillas (" ") que pongo .

```
$cadena_insertar .= '( " ' . $idDetalle . '  "," ' . $variable. ' ")';
```

**Quiero que MYSQL lo reciba de esta forma :**

```
insert into detalle (idDetalle,variable) values (1,Tuberia de acero al carbono Ø4" sch 40)
```

> Pero MYSQL lo recibe como si hubiera enviado 3 datos ya que la 
>   comilla doble (" ") que esta entre  Ø4  y sch lo divide :

```
insert into detalle (idDetalle,variable) values (1 , Tuberia de acero al 
carbono Ø4" , sch 40)
```

**Como podría colocar las comillas para que esa variable no se divida ?**

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo para entender mejor el problema

Comment: INSERT INTO `detalle` (`idDetalle`, `variable`) VALUES ('$idDetalle', '$variable');

Comment: Todo esfuerzo por hacer funcionar una consulta como esa no es otra cosa que perder el tiempo, por un motivo muy simple: cuando esa consulta funcione producirá un código vulnerable, un grave agujero de seguridad en tu sistema. Es como si te esforzaras por hacer funcionar una bomba que te va a explotar en las propias manos. La solución en este caso es aplicar consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recomiendo que para una comprension mas sencilla del string uses un statement con parametros:

```
//Escapamos el caracter " como \"
$variable= "Tuberia de acero al carbono Ø4\" sch 40 ;";

$idDetalle = 1;

//No conozco los detalles de tu conexion, asumire que tenes una variable $conn

//Los signos de interrogacion es donde iran los parametros
$sql = "INSERT INTO detalle (idDetalle,variable) VALUES (?,?);";

//Preparamos la sentencia
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

//Asociamos los parametros a las variables, 
//La cadena "is" significa que el primer parametro sera un entero i
//y el segundo parametro sera una cadena s
$stmt->bind_param("is",$idDetalle,$variable);

//Ejecutamos la sentencia
$stmt->execute();

//Cerramos la sentencia
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Best solution! +1

Comment: una función para escapear parámetros que incluyen caracteres especiales (originalmente pensada para msqli, pero que va bien también para pdo) se encuentra en el manual php:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#121402

Comment: Lo del real escape string es cierto, pero de todas formas en su codigo se ve claramente que su string esta mal escapado en php, la linea `$variable: Tuberia de acero al carbono Ø4" sch 40 ;` claramente no compila. Me parece practico separar lo que es sql de lo que son parametros, ayuda a la legibilidad y a la seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner el codigo de insercion asi

```
$cadena_insertar .= '( " ' . $idDetalle . '  ",".chr(34).$variable.chr(34).")';
```

el chr(34) es un carácter ascii, el 34 que es el de mi respuesta es comillas ("), pongo esta respuesta porque una ves tuve el mismo problema y esto lo soluciono

Comment: por favor añade una explicación a tu respuesta, de paso revisa si eres tan amable [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera puede ser con [Cadenas interpoladas](https://phppot.com/php/variable-interpolation-in-php/)

Cuando la cadena comienza con comillas dobles las variables las puedes pasar en la misma cadena y son sustituidas por sus valores en tiempo de ejecución

```
$string0 = 'PHP';
$string1 = 'Cadenas';
echo "$string0 acepta $string1 interpoladas";
//output: PHP acepta Cadenas interpoladas
```

Así que puedes hacer algo como

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO detalle (idDetalle,variable) VALUES ($idDetalle ,$variable);";
```